# Using Oracle session state, and SessionStateStoreProviderBase in my web.config

Tags: asp.net, oracle, web-config, webserver

Does anyone know or ran into an issue with images not getting rendered when using a custom session state. (I'm using oracle session provider)

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseUri" timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="MyOracleSessionStateStore" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
<providers>
<add name="MyOracleSessionStateStore" type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, Oracle.Web, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="SESSION_STATE"/>
</providers>
</sessionState>
```

It's the weirdest thing to me, i have like 20 pie charts on a page and they are all image controls.
out of those 20, only 10 of them render and when you refresh the page more gets rendered!!
If i change the config file back to InProc or stateServer then it works perfectly.

just random images gets rendered and some images get skipped.
Does anyone know whats going on or have any solutions.
Thanks,
Thanks,

Comment: Still not sure about the cause of this behavior, but we discovered that it only happens on the local host and not the production webserver. I wonder if it has to do with multiple people accessing using the same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seemed to be only on developers local machine using the same port..We haven't had any issues on the production yet.